How can I make closing *Help* kill the buffer?
When I close *Help* by using the GUI it leaves my screen and seemingly buries the buffer, but it does not kill it. To kill it, I need to manually C-x k it. How can I make closing *Help* in the GUI kill it, like any other buffer?

@Drew I like to glance at my list of buffers to confirm that I have all of the buffers open that I wish to be open. Extra buffers pollute the list. And having a buffer that behaves like none other bothers me on principle.

Buffers are a common commodity in Emacs, so you are always going to have extra buffers. It's better to learn how to filter the buffer list for the buffers you are interested in. I recommend ibuffer to the extent that I have rebound C-x C-b to ibuffer. Then I can filter e.g. by mode with / RET org-mode but there are many filters available.

As @lawlist's answer makes clear, "a buffer that behaves like none other" is incorrect. Any special-mode bufffer (including ones that inherit from it) behaves this way (unless they overwrite the q key in the map). That includes help-mode, eww-mode, tar-mode, occur-mode, Info-mode, gnus-mode, etc.: I count 81 such modes in the emacs/lisp directory and its subdirectories. That does not include any such modes defined by third-party packages. As the special-mode docstring says: A special major mode is intended to view specially formatted data rather than files.

The help-mode-map incorporates the special-mode-map, which binds q to quit-window, the doc-string of which states in relevant part:  With prefix argument KILL non-nil, kill the buffer instead of burying it.  Thus, just type C-u q to kill the *Help* buffer and close the window.  If the extra keystrokes to type the universal command feel cumbersome, then consider redefining the keyboard shortcut as follows:
    (define-key help-mode-map "q"
      (lambda () (interactive) (quit-restore-window nil 'kill)))

